# ServiceStack confusion between metadata, OpenAPI, and Swagger

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm working on documentation for an API server implemented using ServiceStack.  I have a few questions.  If it makes more sense, I can move these to separate posts.

1. *IgnoreDataMember* is mentioned in multiple places as the way to hide DTO properties from metadata, but that's not an option if you publish the message to queue since that works via serialization and it skips those fields...
2. The *Exclude* attribute **[Exclude(Feature.Metadata)]** is supposed to hide DTO's from the meatadata page.  While it works at top-level classes, it doesn't filter out properties of a base class.  In other words if MyBaseDto is marked to exlude, but MyEndpointDto inherits from MyBaseDto, properties from both classes are shown.  Is this a bug?
3. Removing services from metadata works really well, but I don't see how to remove them from Swagger/OpenAPI.  I can implement the *OperationFilter* callback, but there's no obvious way there to actually remove anything.  If I use the *ResourceFilterPattern* regex property, it works by DTO, not route.  I'd love to remove any route that starts with /internal for instance.
4. The *LogoUrl* property of the OpenApiFeature and SwaggerFeature doesn't seem to actually affect the page anywhere.  Is there another step to take?
5. On the Swagger UI page, why does every route include the text " XX is not defined!"  I'm not sure what's it's supposed to be pull from.
6. I need help understanding how OpenAPI and Swagger fit together.  Why are they two separate features?  If I just add the OpenAPI feature, I can still bring up the Swagger UI.  What does the Swagger feature bring to the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between ServiceStack's [Swagger Feature](http://docs.servicestack.net/swagger-api) and [Open API](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi) is that Swagger Feature implements the older Swagger 1.2 spec where as Open API implements the newer [Swagger 2.0 spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) which has been renamed from Swagger. If you're unsure which to use, use the newer Open API.

Swagger UI is just the UI and ServiceStack bundles a version of the Swagger UI which works with both the older Swagger 1.2 spec as well as the newer Open API 2.0 spec.

`[Exclude(Feature.Metadata)]` or `[ExcludeMetadata]` works as intended, annotate it on DTOs you wish to exclude from ServiceStack's metadata services which also removes them being included in the returned Swagger/Open API spec + UI.

You can use the `ApiDeclarationFilter` to modify the entire `OpenApiDeclaration` before it's returned, you can remove routes by removing them from the `Paths` Dictionary and Types definitions from being included by removing them from `Definitions` Dictionary. You can submit other feature requests for [missing features you want implemented](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests).

The `LogoUrl` has been fixed for Open API and we've also added `LogoHref` so you can change the url that the logo goes to which by default refreshes the Swagger UI page. This change is available from v4.5.13 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

### Open API is the spec Swagger UI is the UI

The purpose of both Open API and Swagger plugins is to implement the Swagger specification which is a generic and machine readable json format to describe Service APIs. Only one of the benefits is to provide a dynamic UI which ServiceStack provides by bundling the Swagger UI that works with their respective API versions. Other purposes of implementing the Open API spec include enabling automated tooling like [generating a Azure AutoRest client](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi#generating-autorest-client) or importing your Service into [Azure's Management API](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi#publish-azure-management-api).

Comment: Very helpful!  Two other questions though if you could... All response types are getting "<span class="strong">MyResponse is not defined!</span>" in the generated docs.  Also, my question about using "IgnoreDataMember" to hide individual properties.  When I tried that, I lost those values when doing PublishMessage since they aren't serialized.  Am I stuck with an imperative solution to removing individual properties?  Or making a new attribute, of course...

Comment: I figured out why I'm getting "is not defined" anywhere.  I added the ExcludeMetadata to my response base class in order to hide the base class properties, and it actually hid the entire response DTO.  I suppose I can programmatically filter those properties...